# Heatmap with sklearn Confusion Matrix issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I bumped into the following issue:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)

    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

    cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

    sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True)
```

produces the following heatmap:

[image]

problem is that if we print cm, then it shows:

```
[[87  2]
 [ 2 52]]
```

What did I do wrong that prevents 2 and 52 from being displayed in the heatmap?

Comment: What is `y_test`? Did you mean `y_test = model.predict(X_test)`?

Comment: @user2314737 It's a binary problem so `y_test` is basically `y = df["Label"].values` which is being transformed `Y = labelEncoder.fit_transform(y)` to 0s and 1s

Comment: Did you try `annot=cm`?

Comment: @Sirrah just tried it out. doesn't help